# How to set password for redis cluster with spring boot 2.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, redis-cluster

“sorry, my English isn’t very good”.

this is my redis config class:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.redis.cluster")
@Data
public class RedisClusterProperties {
    List<String> nodes;
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

@Autowired
RedisClusterProperties redisClusterProperties;

@Bean
public  RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
    return  new JedisConnectionFactory(
            new RedisClusterConfiguration(redisClusterProperties.getNodes()));
    }
}
```

next is my application.properties

```
spring.redis.cluster.nodes[0] = *.*.*.*:7001
spring.redis.cluster.nodes[1] = *.*.*.*:7002
spring.redis.cluster.nodes[2] = *.*.*.*:7003
spring.redis.cluster.nodes[3] = *.*.*.*:7004
spring.redis.cluster.nodes[4] = *.*.*.*:7005
spring.redis.cluster.nodes[5] = *.*.*.*:7006
```

next is my test-class

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class TestRedis {
    @Autowired
    RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 26 18 ? * *")
    public void scheduler(){
        RedisClusterConnection connection = 
connectionFactory.getClusterConnection();
    
connection.set("java_test".getBytes(),"java_test_value".getBytes());
        final byte[] bytes = connection.get("java_test".getBytes());
        System.out.println("print >> " + new String(bytes));
    }
}
```

then I start my project from application.class.it's normal that I can get /set data from my redis cluster.

Now I set a password for my redis cluster like this:
I update my every redis.conf in linux.

[update redis.conf for add password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1lA3.png)

Then I add ↓↓↓↓ to application.properties in my java project.

```
spring.redis.password=*****
```

I verify redis that it's can use normal.
[redis normal picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6IT2.png)

Then I start my project and find that project is error.

```html
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'testRedis': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'connectionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/hizhu/crawler/brand/config/RedisConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: NOAUTH Authentication required.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1350) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:580) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.hizhu.crawler.brand.CrawlerBrandApplication.main(CrawlerBrandApplication.java:18) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/hizhu/crawler/brand/config/RedisConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: NOAUTH Authentication required.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1708) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: NOAUTH Authentication required.
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processError(Protocol.java:127) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:161) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:215) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:340) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getRawObjectMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:285) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getObjectMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:291) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.clusterSlots(Jedis.java:3376) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterInfoCache.discoverClusterNodesAndSlots(JedisClusterInfoCache.java:54) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterConnectionHandler.initializeSlotsCache(JedisClusterConnectionHandler.java:39) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterConnectionHandler.<init>(JedisClusterConnectionHandler.java:17) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.<init>(JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.java:20) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedisCluster.<init>(BinaryJedisCluster.java:48) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster.<init>(JedisCluster.java:88) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.createCluster(JedisConnectionFactory.java:423) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.createCluster(JedisConnectionFactory.java:393) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet(JedisConnectionFactory.java:350) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

I try to find method from [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisClusterConfiguration.java#L71) that how to deploy . but it's mistake.
I try from reference with spring data [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference). but I can't find method.

please ask Who has met this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Try to set your password in a **RedisClusterConfiguration** in your **RedisConfig** configuration class:

```
@Bean
public  RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){

    RedisClusterConfiguration clusterConf = 
        new RedisClusterConfiguration(
            redisClusterProperties.getNodes());

    clusterConf.setPassword(RedisPassword.of("yourPassword"));

    return new JedisConnectionFactory(clusterConf);
}
```